# Passing pointer array as void pointer to new thread in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, pointers, void

I am currently working on a project where I have to build a shell for a C++ dll, so a new C# GUI can use its functions.
However I got the following problem, in the C++ portion I have to create a new thread for specific reasons, and I want to pass an int array to the new thread.
Note that the values assigned to the array in the function in which this happens are gained from the C# portion of the code.

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void CreateReportPane(int &id, int &what)
{
    DWORD threadId; 
    int iArray[2] = { id, what};    

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, CreateReportPaneThread, iArray, 0,  &threadId);
    if (hThread == NULL) 
    {           
        ExitProcess(3);
    }    
}
```

The problem arises in the new thread, I can reliably fetch the first value out of the array, but the 2nd value seems to be released, here is the code on the other side.

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateReportPaneThread(LPVOID lparam)
{
    int id, what;
    id = *(( int * )lparam);
    what = *(((int *)lparam)+1) ; 
    CreateReportPaneOriginal(id, what);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent the values in the array from getting released while not holding the original thread captive?
A big thank you in advance

Comment: Don't forget to CloseHandle(hThread), else you're going to leak handles and memory.

Comment: I would probably create a structure for this, but if you want to use an array why don't you use array notation in the thread? E.g. `int* iArray = (int*) lparam; int id = iArray[0]; int what = iArray[1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int iArray[2] = { id, what};    

HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(...,CreateReportPaneThread, iArray, ...);
```

The problem is that `iArray` is a local array which means this gets destroyed when the function `CreateReportPane()` returns. So what `CreateReportPaneThread()` refers to doesn't exist. You get the first value just by chance. There is no such guarantee that you would get even the first value.

Use dynamic array:

```
int * iArray  = new int[2];
iArray[0] = id;
iArray[1] = what;

HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(...,CreateReportPaneThread, iArray, ...);
```

Remember to write *deallocate* the array once you're done with it in `CreateReportPaneThread`:

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateReportPaneThread(PVOID *data)
{
     int *array = static_cast<int*>(data);

     int id = array[0], what = array[1];

     delete []array; //MUST DO IT to avoid memory leak!

     //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse, thank you very much people, it solved my problem!

Comment: @wyndesmit: If it solved your problem, you should accept this as "answer" by clicking on the *tick* mark.

Comment: ah yes, I am still new to this interface :)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically allocate the array to prevent the array going out of scope when `CreateReportPane()` exits:

```
int* iArray = new int[2];
iArray[0] = id;
iArray[1] = what;
```

otherwise the thread is accessing an array that is no longer valid, which is undefined behaviour. The thread routine `CreateReportPaneThread()` must then `delete[]` the array when it is no longer required (note the use of `delete[]` and not `delete`).